# Java System.out.format not outputting all information

Tags: java

I am newer to programming and taking an online Java class. I'm making a table that prints out Fahrenheit to Celsius and Celsius to Fahrenheit on the same line. I am supposed to use System.out.format for this problem. But I can only get it to print the first column. This is my System.out.format line:

System.out.format("%3.3f", fahrenheit, fahToCel, "|", celsius, celToFah);

What am I doing wrong?

I can add more code if needed and I hope I explained this problem properly.

Comment: You only have a single format pattern in your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) takes a single format string, then a list of objects to use to 'fill in' the string.

In your case I imagine you want something like

```
System.out.format("%3.3f %3.3f|%3.3f %3.3f", fahrenheit, fahToCel, celsius, celToFah);
```